# How to add conditional scrolling to an extjs Viewport

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have the following Viewport that houses my app...

```
Ext.define('my.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.Viewport',
    id: 'viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    autoDestroy: true,


    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {xtype: "widget.HeaderContainer"},
            {xtype: "widget.BodyContainer"},
            {xtype: "widget.FooterContainer"}
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

As the browser window resizes all the components fill the space nicely but when the window goes below 1024x768 I would like scrollbars to appear.  all the components in the viewport should draw as if the window was 1024x768 (and then go away if the window view is greater than 1024x768 again)

Hope this makes sense. Probably something simple but I couldn't find a way to do this without it being too buggy.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Ext Docs:[The Viewport does not provide scrolling, so child Panels within the Viewport should provide for scrolling if needed using the autoScroll config.](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport)

You'd have to watch for size on each component on the constructor, or initComponent, and do something like

```
constructor:function(config){
    var config= Ext.apply({},config,{    
        autoscroll:((window.innerWidth<1024) && window.innerHeight < 768))?true:false
})
```

Comment: But what if the viewport was resized? Wouldn't all child components have to be _recreated_ when the viewport goes below 1024x768 if you want this to give them scrollbars?

Comment: `viewport.on('resize',` event, and panels have a set autoscroll method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setAutoScroll

Comment: thanks alex.  i think this is the best solution.  i'll post another if i come up with one later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:
Fixed header and footer heights to a specific px value. The center region has a single container with layout=fit (although this is not necessary). This container will get the main app view as an item which means the view will fill whatever space is allocated to it by the viewport. The view that gets put into the center region container will have an autoScroll property set to true and will not specify heights or width. Neither will it's child components.
here is an http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/UqfFH/

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle sample of a nice layout but i'm not looking for any components to ever have a scroll bar.  my app works fine currently and fills the window perfectly.  all i am looking for is a way to make the viewport think that it is 1024x768 regardless of the actual window size.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to use the `minHeight` and `minWidth` configs on the viewport *children*.

You would have to be sure to include the `autoScroll: true` config on the children also.

E.g.: for each of these:

```
this.items = [
    {xtype: "widget.HeaderContainer"},
    {xtype: "widget.BodyContainer"},
    {xtype: "widget.FooterContainer"}
];
```

a simple `minWidth: 1024` config would work fine.

The `minHeight` config would be a little trickier depending on whether or not your `HeaderContainer` and `FooterContainer`are static heights.

If they are then you could simply include a `minHeight` config on the `BodyContainer` which was equivalent to `768 - staticHeaderHeight - staticFooterHeight`.

If you want the header or footer individually resizable also (they are not a static size) you would have to jump through some hoops by resetting the minimum sizes whenever the height of one of the siblings changes.

Comment: good suggestions - hope they are useful to someone's layout
i don't want any of the components to scroll just need the viewport to think it is 1024x768 and draw all the components accordingly even if the window is smaller than that.  i may have to wrap the entire app in another panel with minimum dimensions but was hoping to do this without nesting another component layer